# Why layoutAnimtions in RecyclerView's ItemView cause UI stutters?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation

In my project, I have a list of playing videos, which is built using RecyclerView. When the user clicks to play, the sharing area below the video will have some share icons added (here with LayoutAnimation added), The entire share pannel will stretch; Now The problem is that when user play the video, and quickly or repeatedly slide the list back and forth, the video list will appear disorderly, the video below the screen will be staggered coverage, affecting the user experience, Does someone have encountered this issue, And what is the right way to add item animtion in recyclerView?

code in adpter:

```html
 private void animateExitBottomViews(final VideoClipsPlayViewHolder holder, boolean isFollow) {
        if (null != holder) {
            if (isFollow) {
                holder.ll_share.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.ll_share_abord.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.imgMoreShare.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.imgAllShare.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                holder.imgHead.bringToFront();
                holder.imgAllShare.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.imgMoreShare.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.ll_share.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.ll_share_abord.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                hideFocusButtonWhenFocused(holder);
            }
        }
    }
```

xml file of item layout:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:mgtv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/rl_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:background="@color/skin_color_content_bg_primary">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_player"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_202"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_play"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                android:id="@+id/view_preview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                mgtv:fadeDuration="100"
                mgtv:placeholderImage="@drawable/bg_common_image_holder" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_common_video_play" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_duration"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp_5"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp_5"
                android:background="@drawable/item_vod_landscape_image_text_item_desc_selector"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:minHeight="@dimen/dp_16"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dp_3"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/dp_3"
                android:textColor="@color/color_FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_20" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/fl_player_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_video_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/rl_player"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dp_10"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/dp_10"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/dp_10"
        android:textColor="@color/skin_color_text_primary"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_video_info"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_50"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_video_title">

        <com.mgtv.widget.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_head"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_35"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_35"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp_10"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_comment_avatar_default"
            mgtv:civ_border_color="@color/color_000000_10"
            mgtv:civ_border_width="1px" />

        <com.hunantv.imgo.widget.RoundRectCheckButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_focus"
            style="@style/FollowCheckButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_60"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_26"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp_5"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/img_head"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_username"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp_5"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/img_head"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxEms="8"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/color_888888" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_share_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_40"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            **android:animateLayoutChanges="true"**
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_comment_reply"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_32"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp_3"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txt_praise"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/videoclips_comment_reply"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/dp_3"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="128"
                android:textColor="@color/base_middle_gray"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_20" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp_5"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ll_share_more">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_praise"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_32"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp_6"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_comment_up_default"
                    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/dp_3"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="235"
                    android:textColor="@color/base_middle_gray"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_20" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvLikePlusOne"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:text="@string/plus_one"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_F06000"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_24"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_share"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_wechat_share"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_32"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_32"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:src="@drawable/videoclips_share_wechat" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_wechat_group_share"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_32"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_32"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:src="@drawable/videoclips_share_wechat_group" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_share_abord"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_facebook_share"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_32"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_32"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:src="@drawable/videoclips_share_facebook" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_twitter_share"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_32"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_32"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:src="@drawable/videoclips_share_twitter" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_share_more"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_more_share"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_32"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_32"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp_10"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:src="@drawable/videoclips_share_more"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_all_share"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_32"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_32"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp_10"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:src="@drawable/videoclips_share_all"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/item_bottom_devider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_8"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/frame_video_info"
        android:background="@color/skin_color_divider" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I just dynamically control the visiblity of the share icon, the animate behavior was call by LayoutAnimation, just wondering why the screen will be disorderly when the list is quickly swiped.

[UI STUTTER WHEN FAST SCROLL LIST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnoQd.png)
[NORMAL STATE OF SHARE PANEL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hWPw.png)

[EXPAND STATE OF SHAE PANEL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMvp4.png)

Comment: share the code of the adapter in question

Comment: code has been pasted. the biggest suspect is layoutAnimation, it will be good after remove animtion, but it is necessary for animation here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally,ValueAnimation save my day!

```html
 private ValueAnimator createShareAnimator(final View v, final int start, final int end) {
        ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(start, end);
        animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {
                Integer currentValue = (Integer) animator.getAnimatedValue();
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = v.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.width = currentValue;
                v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            }
        });
        return animator;
    }
```